# Migrating iCloud Store - Fallback Store Being Chosen

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I'm attempting to migrate data from an iCloud store to a local store, since I am removing iCloud syncing from my application (due to instability, users losing data by permanently falling back to the fallback store, etc).

However, when migrating data using `migratePersistentStore` after adding my iCloud persistent store to the persistentStoreCoordinator, it seems as if the actual iCloud store isn't chosen and instead the fallback store is used (`using local storage: 1` can be found in the console prior to the migration, and there doesn't appear to be enough time between this notification and `using local storage: 0`, in which the actual store would be chosen).

How can I migrate the data that is in the user's actual iCloud account, instead of the empty fallback store?

One option that I'm considering is to manually go through the `CoreDataUbiquitySupport` folder (my heuristic being that the largest `.sqlite` file is the best one to migrate) and migrate manually, instead of letting Core Data decide. Is that a valid approach to the problem?

Comment: For anyone reading this, I ended up going through the `CoreDataUbiquitySupport` folder and choosing the best `.sqlite` file to migrate. It seemed to work quite well.